# i am getting syntax error in variables while making calculator i dont know why?

Tags: tkinter, syntax-error, var

well i am startup python by making calculator and not able to understand error my code goes like this

```
import tkinter as Tk

root = Tk()
root.Geometry("250*400+300+300")
root.resizeable(0,0)
root.title("Calculator")

btnrow1 = Frame(root , bg="#00000")
btnrow1.Pack(expand = True, fill = "both",)

btnrow2 = Frame(root)
btnrow2.Pack(expand = True, fill = "both",)

btnrow3 = Frame(root)
btnrow3.Pack(expand = True, fill = "both",)

btnrow4 = Frame(root)
btnrow4.Pack(expand = True, fill = "both",)

btn1 = Button(
     btnrow1,
     text = "1",
     font = ("verdana",22)
)
btn1.Pack(side = LEFT , expand = True,)

root.mainloop()
```

and it throws the syntax error in btnrow2

```
(base) C:\Users\hp\Documents\datascience>python -u "c:\Users\hp\Documents\calculator\calculatormadebyshaan.py"
  File "c:\Users\hp\Documents\calculator\calculatormadebyshaan.py", line 11
    btnrow2 = Frame(root)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

may be it give error later also on `btnrow3`

please help me i am new to python
thanks

Comment: I got `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` at the line `root = Tk()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, your `SyntaxError` is because you are putting commas at the end of your `pack` calls. Correct by simply removing these (e.g. `btnrow1.Pack(expand = True, fill = "both",)` becomes `btnrow1.Pack(expand = True, fill = "both")`). Once you have overcome this problem, you will face a couple of other problems, which are as follows:

1. You are importing `tkinter` using `import tkinter as Tk` but then reference the classes using just their names (i.e. as if you imported using `from tkinter import *`). To resolve this, either change your references to `tkinter` classes from just their names to `Tk.<name>` (e.g. `Tk()` becomes `Tk.Tk()` and `Frame` becomes `Tk.Frame`) or change the import statement to `from tkinter import *`.
2. You are trying to call class methods with a uppercase letter at the start (notably for `Geometry` and `Pack`). These should be completely lowercase (`geometry` and `pack`).

BTW, for the calculator buttons I would recommend you look into the `grid` manager instead of `pack` as this (the 3x3 grid of buttons numbered 1-9) is a textbook example of when it should be used.